# Robotium: Activity not launched for second test

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I have been able to run an android junit test with one test method successfully, but when more than one test method are involved, it just runs the first test and after tearDown, the activity does not relaunch for the subsequent tests. As a result, all my test methods fail, save the first one.

On debugging, I noticed that setUp method launches the MainActivity successfully before running the first testMethod, but on being revisited before the start of second testMethod, the same activity does not get relaunched. The code is as below:

```
package PACKAGE.test;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class Login extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "*.*.MainActivity";
private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
static {
    try {
        launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Login() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    super(launcherActivityClass);
}

private Solo solo;

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Test
public void testLoginScreen() {
    solo.enterText(0, "user-name");
    solo.enterText(1, "pwd");
    solo.clickOnButton("Login");
    solo.waitForActivity("*.*.*.nextActivity");
    solo.clickOnRadioButton(2);
}

@Test
public void testSearch(){
    solo.enterText(0, "user-name");
    solo.enterText(1, "pwd");
    solo.clickOnButton("Login");
    solo.waitForActivity("*.*.*.nextActivity");
    solo.clickOnRadioButton(1);
}


public  void    tearDown()  throws  Exception  { 
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
}

}
```

Comment: It looks ok. Anyway @Test annotation is junit4 annotation. I was sure, that there is no way to run junit4 on android. Do you use junit 3 or junit4?

Comment: Why do you call super.tearDown();? it is not called in the getting started page of robotium. and also super.setUp();

Comment: Apologies for the late reply! yet to get used to the ways of stackoverflow!

Comment: @maszter I'm using junit3 but added junit4 lib after seeing a couple of junit test tutorials. I figure they don't work for Robotium. Have you been able to figure out a way to run more than one test method in one robotium test case?

Comment: @UrielFrankel If I omit the two, only the first test method is executed, after which both the app and the junit test window just freeze over

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. The first test method gets executed, after which the second test method just starts and everything gets freezed. Somebody ought to know the way out of this. Please post an answer!!! :(

Answer (score 3):

You may need to @Override your teardown method

```
@Override
public void tearDown()  throws  Exception  { 
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```